# theme_links for aliased pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I just want to add the 'active' class to all links within the main menu.

The code below works for non-aliased pages.  However, when I run a node that has an alias, the active class does not get applied.

I did verify the code was being triggered.

Any thoughts on how to add a class to the main menu links when viewing a node that has a url alias?

```
function mytheme_links__system_main_menu(array $variables) {

  foreach ($variables['links'] as $key => $link) {
    $variables[$key]['attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
  }

  return theme_links($variables);
}
```

Comment: is that code in your `template.php` file? or registered via `hook_theme` in a module?

Comment: yes, this code is in my template.php file.

Comment: hmmn, couldn't replicate your problem. Though I had to change the code within the for loop to `$variables['links'][$key]['attributes']['class'][] = 'pizza';` to get it to apply the class to every link in the main menu.

Comment: Thanks nmc, I completely overlooked that.  This was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you using main menu links you would be better off using the context module instead of writing the code yourself. It will save time and headache of testing and allow you and your client to edit the the active links through a user interface instead of hard-coding the classes.

Check it out:
http://drupal.org/project/context

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I really did want to understand what it would take to make my code work though.